# React-Native Bundle Error error SHA-1 for file is not computed

Tags: ios, react-native, sha1

I am facing this error while creating bundle of react-native app.

I am executing command **react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios**

```
error SHA-1 for file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js) is not computed. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js) is not computed
    at DependencyGraph.getSha1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:258:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:211:26
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:46:24)
    at _next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:66:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:71:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:63:12
    at Transformer.transformFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:236:7)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:87:34
```

**react-native info** command output

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.3
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 1.73 GB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.19.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 12.2, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 27.0.3, 28.0.3
      System Images: android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: 20.1.5948944
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156
    Xcode: 10.2.1/10E1001 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
    react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    create-react-native-app: 2.0.2
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
    react-native: 0.61.5
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

To solve my issue I have run command with --force option.

**npm install -i -g --force react-native-cli**

This issue was raise due to configure old project with old react-native version. and then trying to run latest react-native ver with new Project.

Comment: Worked, thanks.  `yarn global add react-native-cli && react-native --version`

Comment: for node.js > 16.x, npm i react-native-cli --location=global --force.

Answer (score 17):

install with **npx** 
run 
on windows 10

```
npx react-native run-android
```

on linux

```
npx react-native start
```

Comment: no, using this command we cannot update/install react-native-cli, issue is with react-native-cli and not react-native library.

Answer (score 15):

I resolved the issue in my Mac using

```
npx react-native start
```

Comment: worked in M1 MBP

Comment: When I run without "npx" then CLI bug like title this post.
When I run "npx react-native start ..... npx react-native run-ios" => Everything fixed no bug. :D

Answer (score 8):

For me, I installed the wrong package.

Instead of this:

```
npm i -g react-native
```

Make sure you do this:

```
npm i -g react-native-cli
```

Comment: I had the same here, but had to solve it with `npm i -g react-native-cli --force`

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment so use `npm install -i -g --force react-native-cli` as stated by Punita. It works when it comes to fixing the SHA-1 issue.

But please don't use sudo for any npm related things. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's about version of react-native-cli.

You should try to update.

```
npm i -g react-native-cli
```

Comment: I have tried but not work. I have also tried to uninstall react-native and again install but that also not work.

Answer (score 1):

To solve my issue I have run command with --force option.

npm install -i -g --force react-native-cli

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that this same error happened to me (running on PC, Windows) when I tried to run the gradle command to build an Android release (`./gradlew bundleRelease`).

I found the cause of the issue was due to using Dropbox to sync the folder that this React Native project belonged to, using the Dropbox "Back up your PC automatically" feature, where I had my user Documents folder backed up by Dropbox. Essentially, I would get an error like this:

> error SHA-1 for file C:\Users\Ted
> Zhu\Documents\my-app\MyAppWin\index.js (C:\Users\Ted
> Zhu\Dropbox\PC\Documents\my-app\MyAppWin\index.js)
> is not computed. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
> ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file C:\Users\Ted
> Zhu\Documents\my-app\MyAppWin\index.js (C:\Users\Ted
> Zhu\Dropbox\PC\Documents\my-app\MyAppWin\index.js)
> is not computed

I would notice in the error message, it referred to the same file (index.js) with two different paths:

- C:\Users\Ted Zhu\Documents\my-app\MyAppWin\index.js
- C:\Users\Ted
  Zhu\Dropbox\PC\Documents\my-app\MyAppWin\index.js

This must've been because Dropbox created a symbolic link of the folder so that it would have a path within my Dropbox folder. This appears to cause the file in question to have two paths that refer to the same folder, and trick the Metro bundler into thinking that a SHA hash was not created for one of the project files.

The solution was to move this project to a different directory that is not backed up by Dropbox. In my case, I just created a new folder in my user home directory. Then I was able to successfully run the gradle command to build the Android app.

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS! Thank you. I had tried everything over and over. I was using some symlink folders for convenience and that was the problem. Removed those and it finally worked!

Comment: Of course @TannerLindsay! Looks like the Metro bundler needs to be improved so that it can support symlinks!

Answer (score 1):

For me, global cli update does not work.

[image]

I Just run the command like `yarn react-native bundle`...It works!

`yarn react-native bundle --reset-cache --entry-file index.js --platform ios --bundle-output test.bundle --dev false`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`npx react-native start`

When Metro has started, open another Tab on the terminal, same directory then run:

`npx react-native bundle ...`

The problem for me was not using `npx` for the `react-native` command.

Answer (score 1):

To solve I have run

```
npm install -i -g --force react-native-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I fixed it by install correct react-native-cli:

```
yarn global remove react-native-cli
yarn global add react-native-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem occurred because I was using a node version different from the node version at the time of project setting. Changing the node version solved the problem.

```
nvm use 16
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use your project's local `react-native` command by adding `yarn run` at the beginning to use the project's local `react-native` cli.

```
yarn run react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

I don't really agree with messing up with the global `react-native` command.